Bluetooth not working on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
I recently installed Ubuntu 24.04.1 on my Dell XPS 15 9500. I wanted to toggle on Bluetooth, but it immediately "untoggles" itself.
After quite some searching, finding posts like this (most closely resembles my scenario, I think), this, this, and this one and trying all the given solutions there, I am still stuck. Hence why I am guessing I am not dealing with a duplicate, but a new scenario.
Just as with the referred to posts, here are some details of my machine.

1. sudo dmesg | grep -i blue
The only thing that struck me was the Bluetooth: hci0: Frame reassembly failed (-84) message, which, through search, led me into RaspberryPi issues:
sudo dmesg | grep -i blue
[    2.889068] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.889123] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    2.889125] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.889128] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.889130] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.889133] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.065962] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    4.065966] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    4.065967] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    4.065985] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    4.065988] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    4.065999] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    4.066055] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    4.066118] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[    4.066132] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    4.066134] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[    4.066145] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
[    4.068472] Bluetooth: hci0: setting up ROME/QCA6390
[    4.072734] Bluetooth: hci0: Frame reassembly failed (-84)
[    4.375070] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA Product ID   :0x00000010
[    4.375075] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA SOC Version  :0x400a0200
[    4.375076] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA ROM Version  :0x00000200
[    4.375078] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA Patch Version:0x00000d2b
[    4.375080] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA controller version 0x02000200
[    4.375082] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA Downloading qca/htbtfw20.tlv
[    4.452205] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.452210] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.452213] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    5.318648] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA Downloading qca/htnv20.bin
[    5.535904] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA setup on UART is completed
[   76.562985] audit: type=1107 audit(1734438067.822:241): pid=1249 uid=101 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=5277 label="snap.slack.slack" peer_pid=1248 peer_label="unconfined"


2. sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
All seems active here if you ask me. Just unsure about all the "not supported" messages in there:
sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-12-17 13:33:56 CET; 10min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 7352 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38121)
     Memory: 784.0K (peak: 1.2M)
        CPU: 26ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─7352 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Dec 17 13:33:56 smcvb systemd[1]: Started bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service.
Dec 17 13:33:56 smcvb bluetoothd[7352]: Starting SDP server
Dec 17 13:33:56 smcvb bluetoothd[7352]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support csip plugin
Dec 17 13:33:56 smcvb bluetoothd[7352]: profiles/audio/micp.c:micp_init() D-Bus experimental not enabled
Dec 17 13:33:56 smcvb bluetoothd[7352]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support micp plugin
Dec 17 13:33:56 smcvb bluetoothd[7352]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support vcp plugin
Dec 17 13:33:56 smcvb bluetoothd[7352]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support mcp plugin
Dec 17 13:33:56 smcvb bluetoothd[7352]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support bass plugin
Dec 17 13:33:56 smcvb bluetoothd[7352]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support bap plugin
Dec 17 13:33:56 smcvb bluetoothd[7352]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized


3. lsusb; sudo dmesg| grep -i firm
lsusb; sudo dmesg| grep -i firm
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04d9:0339 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. USB-HID Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 27c6:533c Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. FingerPrint
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:5510 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2109:2817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 24ae:1100 Shenzhen Rapoo Technology Co., Ltd. Rapoo 2.4G Wireless Device
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 2109:0817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB3.0 Hub             
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub


4. rfkill list all
rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no


5. bluetoothctl devices
bluetoothctl 
Waiting to connect to bluetoothd...[bluetooth]# Agent registered
[bluetooth]# devices
No default controller available
[bluetooth]# 


6. lsmod | grep bluetooth
lsmod | grep bluetooth
bluetooth            1028096  15 btrtl,btqca,btintel,hci_uart,btbcm,bnep
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth


I am a little bit at a loss at this stage. So, any help would be much appreciated.

About that lsmod command, on my system, my Bluetooth adapter uses the btusb module for a drive, which I doubt would show up with that grep command. Of course, it might be different for you.

Thanks for the hint nonetheless, @TSJNachos117. Running "lsmod | grep btusb" results in no output for me, sadly.
